# NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration ignores arguments despite not being sandboxed

Tags: swift, cocoa, macos-catalina, appkit, nsworkspace

I'm trying to launch an application using the `open` tool through Swift. I have two seperate implementations, one with `NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at:configuration)` for 10.15+ and one with `NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(at:options:configuration)` for 10.14 and lower. Everything works fine on 10.14 and below but Catalina is ignoring any arguments thrown at it. **The app is not sandboxed.**

Implementation for 10.15+:

```swift
let appPath = URL(string: "file:///usr/bin/open")!
let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.arguments = [
    "-a",
    executablePath,
    url.absoluteString
]

NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: appPath, configuration: configuration) { (app, error) in
    if let error = error {
        done(error)
    } else {
        done(nil)
    }
}
```

Running this results in a Terminal window opening `/usr/bin/open` with no arguments, then closing the session.

[image: Catalina opening a Terminal]

`executablePath` is a string to an application's executable, e.g. `/Application/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`

`url` is a URL object containing an http or https link

Removing `file://` from appPath also works fine in 10.14, but on 10.15 results in `The application “open” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around this problem in a different way. Instead of using `NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at:configuration:)` I'm now invoking a `Process` that opens `open`.

This also works on versions below Catalina and even works **with sandboxing**. However, there's a catch to sandboxing, read more at the end.

#### Workaround

```swift
let task = Process()
        
task.arguments = ["-a", executablePath, url.absoluteString]
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/open"
task.launch()
```

No need for waiting for the process as a) the return of open isn't that useful and b) it's almost immediately anyway.

#### Regarding Sandboxing

Apple states:

> In a sandboxed application, child processes created with the Process class inherit the sandbox of the parent app.

This means that the application opened using `Process` has the same sandbox. If you use `open` to open a URL like I do that's fine because `open` spawns a new process without our sandbox anyway. However this does mean that you cannot use this open other regular apps unless this app is working fine with your sandbox.